# AndroidTv ongoing recommendation style

Tags: android, notifications, android-tv

I have a video playback activity which creates a media session so I can exit the app and see the ongoing recommendation card with the current playing media. I have achieved this following the documentation, but the problem is that I want to change fastlane color and app icon on the card. How can I achieve this? The system is creating the recommendation for me thanks to the `MediaSession` if set active.
Can I pass some style to the session, or the only possible way would be to use recommendation builder and create the recommendation for my self manualy?

Answer (score 0):

You can set badge icon using the builder and also is possible to set content image.

```
ContentRecommendation.Builder builder = new ContentRecommendation.Builder();
builder.setBadgeIcon(R.drawable.videos_by_google_icon)
builder.setContentImage(bitmap);
```

Comment: I am not using a builder. The OS is doing it for me. I just create a `MediaSession` and I set it as active. When I hit the home button I have the recommendation there.

Comment: Then try setting metadata using MediaMetadata.Builder on mediasession object.

Comment: Could you provide an example?